# django-session-timeout: how to disconnect automatically (without user action)

Tags: django, logout, session-timeout

I am newbie in Django and try to implement 'autologout' using a tierce app django-session-timeout
It works but I would like to improve behavior

the session expire after time set in settings.py but there is no refresh so that it is disconnect and redirect to login page except if user click elsewhere

in other word, the user is disconnect (as user session expire) but not automatically redirect to login page -> need a user event

is it possible to improve this without writing my own middleware?

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
]

LOGIN_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 900  # 900 - >15 minutes = 15 * 60
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```